# How to pass a parameter to IActionFilter attribute?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create my custom attribute using `IActionFilter`:

Attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorize : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyAuthorize() : base(typeof(MyAuthorizeImplement))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { Id };
    }

    private class MyAuthorizeImplement : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly int _id;

        public MyAuthorizeImplement(int id)
        {
            _id = id;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {                
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = $"Id: {_id}"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyAuthorize(Id = 1)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result content:

> Id: 0

I've tried many times with the difference `Id` values, but `_id` is still `0` as default. Then I've tried to change the value types of `Id`, `id` and `_id` from `int` to `string` and pass some value but it's still `null`:

```
[MyAuthorize(Id = "abc")]
```

Do I miss something? Thank you!

P/S: I also tried this way, it worked but I don't want to use it:

Inside the constructor, tried to use `id` as a parameter instead of a property:

```
// public int Id { get; set; }

public MyAuthorize(int id) : base(typeof(MyAuthorizeImplement))
{
    Arguments = new object[] { id };
}
```

Action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyAuthorize(id: 1)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Result content:

> Id: 1

In the first case, the constructor doesn't require any parameter, it's an option but in the second it does. That's why I don't want to use it.

When I need some `rule` (as `Id`, `Roles`, `Name`...), I can pass it. Otherwise, leave it empty. Just like `Authorize` attribute:

```
[Authorize] -> All login user can assign
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] -> Only user with this role can assign
```

Comment: At the time your constructor runs, `Id` has not been explicitly set. Your property initializer runs *after* the constructor. Your argument array will always have the default value of the field (0,null,etc). You'll have to use the constructor parameters if that is how you intend on creating the array. Alternatively you could maybe have a full bodied setter (not an auto property) and recreate the array within the `set` body. You might also consider decompiling the authorize attribute (with dot Peek or similar) and see how they handle it.

Comment: Your other option is to have your *attribute* itself implement the `IActionFilter` interface. That's how the authorize attribute is done: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you! I've tried again. I really get the value but after that, it will be reset. It followed these steps: constructor -> property -> constructor -> OnActionExecuting. [Snapshot](https://image.ibb.co/ct1YiT/Untitled.png)

Comment: Read my comment again. Inside your setter you need to recreate the arguments array. `set {_id=value;Arguments = new object[] { Id };} `

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Perfect! Thank you so much! You can write it as an answer that I can accept it.

Comment: It's still probably not the correct way of doing this so I'd rather not

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I see that this way is as same as the way in the link you gave me above. They didn't use constructor, too. And they used string array instead of Arguments.

Comment: Can you not overload the constructor and explicitly pass in the value and set it? `public MyAuthorize(int id){}`

Comment: @Wurd I can, but I don't want to use it. I got the solution based on #pinkfloydx33's comments. Although there are still a lot of small troubles to make it run perfect. We still need a constructor. We also want an instance of a class if there are multiple properties which have the same type.

Comment: Just an aside - you can have multiple named optional parameters in constructors, in addition to your normal empty constructor? `public MyAuthorize(){}` `public MyAuthorize(int? id = null){}` When new devs see your class they would be able to guess it's functionality through intellisense by looking through it's constructor arguments, which can be helpful :)

Comment: @Wurd It wouldnot work in this case: `[MyAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]` or `[MyAuthorize(Name = "user01")]`. The types of both `Roles` and `Name` are `string` and they can be declared as the first parameter. We cannot implement it inside the constructor.